# How to reload, stop, back & forward a frame?

Tags: javascript, html, frames

I got the following:

```
<frameset cols="20%,80%">
<frame src="zone1.htm" id="zone1">
<frame src="http://www.google.com" id="zone2">
</frameset>
```

I got access to zone1.htm and the second frame is loaded from an external website, i want to do using javascript: Reload + Stop + Back + Forward Controls in zone1.htm to control the google frame.

I'm not sure if this is forbidden too by the same origin policy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.history.forward()
window.history.back();
window.location.reload();
```

where window is the `window` object. A frame's window object can be access in this way:

```
frames.zone2.window;
```

Use name then, instead of ID. Or use numeric indexes:
    frames[0].window;

Today's browser often limit these features as a security enhancement (you don't want an advertisement to redirect you back the whole time)